# PubNub subscriber coded in AngularJS and save info to Mongo DB

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, pubnub

I tried to subscribe a message by PubNub channel using AngularJS and insert the received data in to MongoDB but I already understood that I can't do to directly. In this case, I searched many thinks to fix this question. Anyone can explain me how I can insert the received data on my database?

I use this code to subscribe:

```
angular.module('PubNubAngularApp', ["pubnub.angular.service"]).controller('ChatCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $location, PubNub) {

PubNub.init({
  subscribe_key: '(....)',
  publish_key: '(....)',
});
$rootScope.initialized = true;

PubNub.ngSubscribe({ 
channel: '(...)',
callback: function(m) {
    console.log(m);
},
error: function(err) {
  console.log(err);
} });
});
```

Best Regards,

Comment: Is your subscriber receiving the published messages? If so, it is just a Angular and/or Mongo issue from there. But why is your database on an Angular client? Shouldn't it be on a server? Just curious what your use case is.

Comment: Yes, my subscriber receive the published messages. The database is on server and not on Angular client. My doubt persist on how I can access the MongoDB database. I can't insert the data of subscribed message into Mongo directly?

Answer (score 0):

## Use PubNub BLOCKS to save messages to your database

PubNub BLOCKS will let you make an `xhr` request to `POST` the data from within PubNub (while the message is in progress) to your server to store it in your database.

See the full [BLOCKS catalog for pre-packaged solutions](https://www.pubnub.com/blocks-catalog/). You will need to reference the [Using external REST APIs documentation](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/blocks/tutorials/xhr) to get started on what you need to do.